# Administer asp.net website (create new users, assign users to roles, etc.) from a windows app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have an asp.net web app that uses forms-based authentication, a SqlMembershipProvider (using an encrypted password format), and a SqlRoleProvider. I need to know if it's possible to administer the users (create new users, assign them to roles, etc.) from a windows application - the powers that be don't want any administrative functionality in the web app itself.

Here is the membership provider definition from web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
         applicationName="/MyWebApp"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Encrypted"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And the role manager definition:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyRoleManager"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
         connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
         applicationName="/MyWebApp" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And here is the machineKey definition (necessary to be able to use encrypted passwords):

```
<machineKey
    validationKey="BC50A82A6AF6A015C34C7946D29B817C00F04D2AB10BC2128D1E2433D0E365E426E57337CECAE9A0681A2C736B9779B42F75D60F09F142C60E9E0E8F9840DB46"
      decryptionKey="122035576C5476DCD8F3611954C837CDA5FE33BCDBBF23F7"
      validation="SHA1"
      decryption="AES"/>
```

So, obviously, I have a Sql Server database that contains the users and roles for the web app. I'd like to create a separate windows app that references the web app assembly, and use the configured MembershipProvider, RoleProvider, and machineKey to create users, assign users to roles, etc. If that's not possible, I can duplicate the configuration settings from web.config within the windows app. But I don't know how to do this either.

Am I way out of line thinking that this is possible? I've tried googling for a solution, but the signal-to-noise ratio is really bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a solution, based on the other answers (who both got +1), and [some other](http://blogs.msdn.com/saurabhd/archive/2006/08/02/685552.aspx) [sites](http://forums.asp.net/p/1426317/3190758.aspx#3190758) [out there](http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm).

First, I created Application Config file (app.config). It mirrors exactly what is found in web.config from the web app, with the exception of how the connection string was handled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="connectionStrings" type="System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString ="SERVER=abc;UID=def;PWD=hij;Initial Catalog=klm;MultipleActiveResultsets=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>

    <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
             applicationName="/MyWebApp"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             passwordFormat="Encrypted"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleManager">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlRoleManager"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
             connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"
             applicationName="/MyWebApp" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <machineKey
      validationKey="BC50A82A6AF6A015C34C7946D29B817C00F04D2AB10BC2128D1E2433D0E365E426E57337CECAE9A0681A2C736B9779B42F75D60F09F142C60E9E0E8F9840DB46"
      decryptionKey="122035576C5476DCD8F3611954C837CDA5FE33BCDBBF23F7"
      validation="SHA1"
      decryption="AES"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Then I created a helper class that provides access to two singletons: a `MembershipProvider` and a `RoleProvider`. This turned out to be easier than I thought, once I knew how to do it:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebAdminViaWindows
{
    internal static class Provider
    {
        private static readonly string assemblyFilePath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        static Provider()
        {
            Membership = CreateMembershipProvider();
            Role = CreateRoleProvider();
        }

        public static MembershipProvider Membership { get; private set; }
        public static RoleProvider Role { get; private set; }

        private static MembershipProvider CreateMembershipProvider()
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(assemblyFilePath);

            var systemWebGroup = config.SectionGroups["system.web"];
            if (systemWebGroup == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("system.web group not found in configuration");
            }

            var membershipSection = systemWebGroup.Sections["membership"];
            if (membershipSection == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("membership section not found in system.web group");
            }

            var defaultProviderProperty = membershipSection.ElementInformation.Properties["defaultProvider"];
            if (defaultProviderProperty == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("defaultProvider property not found in membership section");
            }

            var defaultProviderName = defaultProviderProperty.Value as string;
            if (defaultProviderName == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("defaultProvider property is not a string value");
            }

            var providersProperty = membershipSection.ElementInformation.Properties["providers"];
            if (providersProperty == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("providers property not found in membership section");
            }

            var providerCollection = providersProperty.Value as ProviderSettingsCollection;
            if (providerCollection == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("providers property is not an instance of ProviderSettingsCollection");
            }

            ProviderSettings membershipProviderSettings = null;

            foreach (ProviderSettings providerSetting in providerCollection)
            {
                if (providerSetting.Name == defaultProviderName)
                {
                    membershipProviderSettings = providerSetting;
                }
            }

            if (membershipProviderSettings == null)
            {
                if (providerCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    membershipProviderSettings = providerCollection[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("No providers found in configuration");
                }
            }

            var provider = new SqlMembershipProvider();
            provider.Initialize("MySqlMembershipProvider", membershipProviderSettings.Parameters);
            return provider;
        }

        private static RoleProvider CreateRoleProvider()
        {
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(assemblyFilePath);

            var systemWebGroup = config.SectionGroups["system.web"];
            if (systemWebGroup == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("system.web group not found in configuration");
            }

            var roleManagerSection = systemWebGroup.Sections["roleManager"];
            if (roleManagerSection == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("roleManager section not found in system.web group");
            }

            var defaultProviderProperty = roleManagerSection.ElementInformation.Properties["defaultProvider"];
            if (defaultProviderProperty == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("defaultProvider property not found in roleManager section");
            }

            var defaultProviderName = defaultProviderProperty.Value as string;
            if (defaultProviderName == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("defaultProvider property is not a string value");
            }

            var providersProperty = roleManagerSection.ElementInformation.Properties["providers"];
            if (providersProperty == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("providers property not found in roleManagerSection section");
            }

            var providerCollection = providersProperty.Value as ProviderSettingsCollection;
            if (providerCollection == null)
            {
                throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("providers property is not an instance of ProviderSettingsCollection");
            }

            ProviderSettings roleProviderSettings = null;

            foreach (ProviderSettings providerSetting in providerCollection)
            {
                if (providerSetting.Name == defaultProviderName)
                {
                    roleProviderSettings = providerSetting;
                }
            }

            if (roleProviderSettings == null)
            {
                if (providerCollection.Count > 0)
                {
                    roleProviderSettings = providerCollection[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("No providers found in configuration");
                }
            }

            var provider = new SqlRoleProvider();
            provider.Initialize("MySqlRoleManager", roleProviderSettings.Parameters);
            return provider;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point all that's needed is to access the `Membership` and `Role` properties of the `Provider` class. As an example, the following prints out the first 10 users and their roles:

```
int total;
foreach (MembershipUser user in Provider.Membership.GetAllUsers(0, 10, out total))
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(user.UserName);
    foreach (var role in Provider.Role.GetRolesForUser(user.UserName))
    {
        sb.AppendLine("\t" + role);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Impressive.  I didn't realize it could be that simple.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

- You could use the [Web Site
  Administration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx), which isn't
  Windows-Forms-based, but isn't part
  of your Web app, either.  It comes
  with Visual Studio and can be
  accessed by clicking the ASP.NET
  Configuration icon in the Solution
  Explorer.
- It's possible to directly manipulate
  the provider database used by a
  SqlMembershipProvider from a Windows
  Forms app, but you might have to be
  careful not to break things.
- If you were to create a custom
  membership provider, you'd be in
  control of how membership and role
  data is persisted.  If you did that
  you could create a reusable library
  that could be used in the Web app and
  a Windows Forms app, too.

I don't think trying to use a SqlMembershipProvider from a Windows Forms app is a practical approach.

Comment: It works from VS, but can you use the Web Site Administration Tool in a production environment?

Comment: @fre0n:  Technically yes, but it's not simple.  Description here: http://forums.asp.net/p/932674/1155428.aspx  I would look into the other options I mentioned for that.

Comment: This is a good suggestion... your best bet to do this easily.  Otherwise, you're better off creating your own Membership and Role provider.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "best-practice" would be here, but a simple way that *should* work is this.

- Make a new windows app
- Add an Application Config file
  (app.config)
- Copy the appropriate settings into
  the app.config (settings from above
  ^)
- Add a reference to System.Web
- And copy the code from your web app
  that uses the above settings to
  connect to the database

That should do what you want.

Comment: I can instantiate a SqlMembershipProvider and a SqlRoleProvider and set *almost* all necessary properties, but how do I give them a connection string? And how would I provide the SqlMembershipProvider with validation and decryption keys?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider_members.aspx, there is no property or method to set the connection string of a SqlMembershipProvider.

Comment: You should be able to do all of that in the same way as you are doing in your web app. I assume you are using similar code in your web app for users to login?

Comment: In a web app the initialization is all done automagically. You never have to manually call the `Initialize` method of the `SqlMembershipProvider`. Plus, I was using a Login Control, so I never even touched the `SqlMembershipProvider`.